# What is the boundary of an open subset $\Omega \subset \Bbb H$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis

> Let $\Bbb H:=\{(x,y): x\in \Bbb R, y>0\}$ and $\Omega$ an open subset of $\Bbb H$. Then what is $\partial \Omega$ ?

Of course $\partial \Omega =\overline{\Omega} \setminus {\Omega}$. Now the point is while considering $\overline{\Omega}$ is it $\overline{\Omega}$ as a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ or $\overline{\Omega} \cap \Bbb H$ ? For instance, let $\Omega=\{(x,y) :x \in \Bbb R, y>0, x^2+y^2<1\}$ . Then $\Omega$ is clearly an open subset of $\Bbb H$, then is $\partial \Omega = \{(x,y) :x \in \Bbb R, y>0, x^2+y^2=1\}$ or $\{(x,y) :x \in \Bbb R, y\ge 0, x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,0):-1 \le x \le 1\}$ ?

> As we are considering it as a subset of the upper half plane, while considering its boundary shouldn't we only consider its boundary in the upper half plane, as we are treating it as the ambient space to start off with?

Comment: I'm not so sure of the accepted answer, I mean it depends whether we consider the $\mathbb R^2$ topology or the induced topology based on $\mathbb H$. I'n not saying the answer is false, but I rather think it has to be explicitly stated in the problem otherwise I would go for the standard $\mathbb R^2$ one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your $\Omega$ we have $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb H : x^2+y^2<1
\}$ and has
$$\partial\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb H : x^2+y^2=1
\}.$$

For the closure, this is
$\overline \Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb H : x^2+y^2\le1
\}$

Comment: Thanks. So we just need to focus on $\Bbb H$ !

Comment: surely that is the trick